# Cross dependencies without forward declaring all used functions?

Tags: c++

I have class A (in A.h) which depends on class B in (B.h) and vice versa. Forward declaring the used functions works, but this means I have to update everywhere where I forward declared those functions in the future, ex, if I remove, or change argument in those functions they must all be updated to reflect change. I don't feel this is good practice. Is there a way around this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only need to work with *pointers* or *references* to a class at the declaration level, you can do it like this:

### A.h

```
class B; // forward class declaration

class A {
    A(B &);
};
```

### B.h

```
class A;

class B {
    B(A &);
};
```

### B.cpp

```
#include "B.h"
#include "A.h" // now we get the full declaration of A

B::B(A &a) {
    a.foo(5);
}
```

Mutual dependencies like this are tough to deal with but sometimes unavoidable.

If `A` and `B` depend on the *implementations* of each other, then you've got a system design problem that you need to resolve before proceeding further.

Comment: B doesn't call that inside the *header file*, does it? I'll add a `.cpp` file example.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to have a forward declaration header:

a.fwd.h

```
#pragma once
class A;
```

a.h

```
#pragma once
#include "a.fwd.h"
#include "b.fwd.h"
class A
{
    A(B*);
};
```

etc.

This way, each class provides its own forward declarations - localised alongside the header where it belongs - checked for consistency with the real declarations and definitions by including the forward declaration header in the header, and the header in the implementation.