# Overloading in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am not sure if I am doing the overload correctly.

...\point.h(42) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Vec3'
Point operator +(Vec3 a) const;

Here is my .h file:

```
    #include <fstream>
    #include <iostream>
    #include "vec3.h"

    using std::ofstream;
    using std::ifstream;
    using std::cout;
    using std::cin;
    using std::endl;
    using namespace std;

    #ifndef POINT_H
    #define POINT_H

    //Define ourselves a basic 2D point class
    class Point
    {

        friend ofstream& operator <<(ofstream& output, const Point& p);
        friend ifstream& operator >>(ifstream& input, Point& p);
\    
        public:

        Point();
        Point(double _x, double _y);
        Point(double _x, double _y, double _z);

        double x,y,z;

        //Operators
        Point operator -(Point a) const;
        Point operator /(double s) const;
        Point operator *(double s) const;

        // Used to do vector point addition
        Point operator +(Vec3 a) const;

    };

    #endif
```

Here is my .cpp file

```
#include "point.h"

Point::Point(double _x, double _y, double _z)
{
    x= _x;
    y= _y;
    z= _z;
}

Point :: Point()
{
    x = 0.0;
    y = 0.0;
    z = 0.0;
}

Point::Point(double _x, double _y)
{
    x= _x;
    y= _y;
    z= 0;
}

    Point Point::operator -(Point a) const
    {
        return Point(x-a.x, y-a.y, z-a.z);
    }

    Point Point::operator /(double s) const
    {
        return Point(x/s, y/s, z/s);
    }

    Point Point::operator *(double s) const
    {
        return Point(x*s, y*s, z*s);
    }


// Vector Point Addition
    Point Point::operator +(Vec3 a) const
    {
        return Point(x+a.x, y+a.y, z+a.z);
    }

    ofstream& operator <<(ofstream& output, const Point& p)
    {
        output << p.x << " " << p.y << " " << p.z << "\n";
        return output;
    }

    ifstream& operator >>(ifstream& input, Point& p)
    {
        input >> p.x >> p.y >> p.z;
        return input;
    }
```

Here is the Vec3.h

```
    #ifndef VEC3_H
#define VEC3_H

#include "point.h"

class Vec3
{
    friend ofstream& operator <<(ofstream& output, const Vec3& p);
    friend ifstream& operator >>(ifstream& input, Vec3& p);

    public: 
    Vec3();
    Vec3(double _x, double _y);
    Vec3(double _x, double _y, double _z);

    double x,y,z;

    //Operators
    Vec3 operator -(Vec3 a) const;
    Vec3 operator /(double s) const;
    Vec3 operator *(double s) const;

    // Used to do vector Vec3 addition
    Vec3 operator +(Vec3 a) const;
    Point operator +(Point a) const;

};

#endif
```

Comment: Could you post the vec3.h file?

Comment: Hard to say without vec3.h. One thing you should note is that it's good to have const references to arguments in operators, as long as you'r passing classes and structs.

Comment: Check out for **typo** in vec3.h.. whether the class name is `vec3` or `Vec3` something lik dat.. Compiler clearly tells it can't identify `Vec3`...

Comment: @dutt, So I should pass in consts for my arguments?

Comment: Generally, it's bad style to have `using` declarations in header files, because then anybody who includes your header file gets those `using` declarations whether they want them or not. Instead, use fully qualified names in your header file (`std::ofstream` instead of just `ofstream`).

Comment: @Aero: for every one that doesn't take a pod, plain old data, i.e. char, int, double etc etc. Those should be just const. For example operator+(const Vec3& operand); and operator+(const double operand). And observe Gregs point as well, very important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vec3.h` includes `point.h` and `point.h` includes `vec3.h`.  You need to remove the circular dependency, by forward declaring one of the classes.

Comment: Good spotting! I just wrote an answer about that, too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939151/cross-dependencies-without-forward-declaring-all-used-functions