# Another "x" does not name a type error

Tags: c

Unlike a lot of the other 'x' does not name a type errors on here, I don't think this one involves circular dependencies, but I'm still having trouble figuring it out.

```
typedef struct        /* structure definitions */
{
   float  mat[4][4];
}  matrix_unit;

matrix_unit I = {
{ 1., 0., 0., 0.,
  0., 1., 0., 0.,
  0., 0., 1., 0.,
  0., 0., 0., 1  },
};

matrix_unit *stack[50];    /* (line 456) array of pointers to act as a stack */
matrix_unit stackbase = I;
stack[0] = &stackbase;  // 'stack' does not name a type
```

Since stack has already been declared as a stack of pointers to matrix_unit structs, shouldn't this be valid?

When I compile the code with "gcc -c 3D.c", I get the following errors from these lines:

```
3D.c:457:1: error: initializer element is not constant
3D.c:458:1: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
3D.c:458:1: error: conflicting types for ‘stack’
3D.c:456:14: note: previous declaration of ‘stack’ was here
3D.c:458:1: error: invalid initializer
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Compiling fine with gcc 4.6.2

Comment: Hmm.. Well I'm including from a C++ file. Should that effect anything? I'm compiling that with g++

Comment: Compiling fine with g++ 4.6.2 too. So this is not a compiler issue for this subset. however i could only test what you wrote in your post.

Comment: Should I post more of the code? This file is included from a cpp file, but I'm not sure how anything else would effect it.

Comment: I'm running g++ 4.5.2 on ubuntu.

Comment: You can post more code, but that won't mean we will be able to help you. I will try though. Regards

Comment: Compiled fine on my ubuntu box with g++ 4.5.2 :s

Comment: You have multiple declarations for the type `stack` in your program, notice the errors *3D.c:458:1: error: conflicting types for ‘stack’ 3D.c:456:14: note: previous declaration of ‘stack’ was here* So you need to hunt down why is that happening, perhaps some header file or library you link to declares a type with same name. A quick check is to, Change the type name to something else and see if it compiles cleanly.

Comment: Make sure you aren't accidentally including any pre-defined definitions for `stack`, such as stl's stack, or another one you defined yourself.

Comment: Ok from your last edit i migth have understood. It may be cross declaration that could cause a multiple declaration of type `stack`. Maybe this could give you a hint http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939151/cross-dependencies-without-forward-declaring-all-used-functions

Comment: I include stdio.h, math.h, GL/gl.h, GL/glu.h, and stdlib.h. I don't think these contain stack in them, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler is trying to parse line 458 as a declaration.  It is not, it is a statement.  Statements must be written inside a function.  Like this:

```
void initialize() 
{
    stack[0] = &stackbase;
}
```